# Recreating this image using Tikz with flattened circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, shapes

I am trying to recreate this image: 
[image]

I'm however struggling with the flattened circle shape in the centre as well as getting the curved lines for focusing. My current attempt has allowed me to get this far:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (2.4);
\draw [red, dashed] (0,0) circle (1.8);
\draw [<-, red, thick] (1.3,1.3) -- (2.3,2.3) node[above] {equilibrium orbit};
\draw    (0,2.4) to[out=-50,in=130] (0,-2.4);
\draw    (1.8,1.6) to[out=-60,in=100] (-1.85,-1.5);
\draw    (-2.1,1.2) to[out=40,in=220] (2.1,-1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the pictures below: 
[image]

However I am struggling to get any further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,
    declare function={rr(\t)=1.8*(1+0.01*rnd)*(1+0.1*sin(-45+3*\t));}]
 \draw plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,10,...,350}] (\t:{rr(\t)});
 \draw (0,0) circle[radius=2.4cm];
 \draw[red, dashed] (0,0) circle[radius=1.8cm];
 \draw[<-, red, thick] (1.3,1.3) -- (3,2) node[right] {equilibrium orbit};
 \foreach \X in {80,200,320}
 {\draw (\X:2.4) to[bend right] (0,0) to[bend left] (\X+180:2.4);
 \path (\X-30:2.5) node[anchor=\X-30+180]{Hill}
 (\X+30:2.5) node[anchor=\X+30+180]{Valley};  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]